# Changing Ruby Database Tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, attributes

When I go in the rails console and do the command River.all to see my database, it still has the attributes from the first block of code and not the second one where I have updated what attributes each river has. How do I fix this?

Original db/migrate/12123234125_create_rivers :

```
class CreateRivers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :rivers do |t|
      t.date :date
      t.decimal :level
      t.integer :river_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Changed Version:

```
class CreateRivers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :rivers do |t|
      t.string :river_id
      t.string :display
      t.integer :river_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Also I  have this in my data_import.rake file

```
 task rivers: :environment do

 doc = REXML::Document.new File.new("#{root_dir}/config/RiverStations.xml")
 doc.elements.each("DEFINITIONS/STATIONS/STATION") { |element| 
  river = River.create(river_id: element.attributes["ID"], display: element.attributes["DISPLAY"],  river_name: element.attributes["RIVER_NAME"])
}
```

Is it possible that this isn't loaded before I check or something?

The error you asked for:

```
Jennys-MacBook-Pro:dashboard jennymandl$ rake db:migrate --trace
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
== 20140609150804 CreateRivers: migrating =====================================
-- create_table(:rivers)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

undefined method `write' for :display:Symbol/Users/jennymandl/Desktop/dashboard/db/migrate/20140609150804_create_rivers.rb:5:in `display'
/Users/jennymandl/Desktop/dashboard/db/migrate/20140609150804_create_rivers.rb:5:in `block in change'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:198:in `create_table'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:649:in `block in method_missing'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:621:in `block in say_with_time'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/benchmark.rb:281:in `measure'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:621:in `say_with_time'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:641:in `method_missing'
/Users/jennymandl/Desktop/dashboard/db/migrate/20140609150804_create_rivers.rb:3:in `change'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:595:in `exec_migration'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:579:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/benchmark.rb:281:in `measure'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:578:in `block in migrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:294:in `with_connection'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:577:in `migrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:752:in `migrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:992:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1038:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:211:in `block in transaction'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:219:in `within_new_transaction'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:211:in `transaction'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1038:in `ddl_transaction'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:991:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:953:in `block in migrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:949:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:949:in `migrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:807:in `up'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:785:in `migrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:34:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.1/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/usr/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
Jennys-MacBook-Pro:dashboard jennymandl$
```

Comment: Did you `run rake db:migrate` after changing the ***migration*** file?

Comment: I did and this is what I got irb(main):002:0> rake db:migrate
NameError: undefined local variable or method `migrate' for main:Object

Comment: well then I exited the ruby console and did it just in the terminal for the directory of my app and then when I went back to the console and did River.all nothing had changed

Comment: You will need drop your database or run rollback in order to re run your modified migration. rake db:migrate:up VERSION=$TIMESTAMP, Make sure to drop table on your migration, doing a down method.

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: If you ran rake db:migrate and after your made the change , rails won't run that migration again, so if you modify that file rails doesn't run that migration again. You need to rollback that migration, or drop your database (if you are on dev). If you are in production you sould create a new migration that modified the schema.

Comment: how do you create a new migration to modify the schema?

Comment: Create a new migration and change that table look at http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#changing-tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've changed a migration after running it you will need to undo that migration then run it again.

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#rolling_back

Please read through this whole page as it is very instructive.

To roll back your migration, and run it again, do

```
rake db:migrate:down VERSION=12123234125
rake db:migrate
```

EDIT:  added info on how to actually down and up a migration, and also updated the link as it was actually from a Rails 3 version.

Comment: Can I just change things in schema.rb?

Comment: No.  schema.rb is written to by the system and is really just a form of automatically generated documentation.  All schema changes need to be done via migrations.

Comment: I did that and now when I type in River.all it says no such table found

Comment: It sounds like you have run the migration down, to get rid of the table, but haven't run it up again.  Did you do the second part of my answer, `rake db:migrate`?  Did it successfully complete?

Comment: I tried rake db:migrate and it said == 20140609150804 CreateRivers: migrating =====================================
-- create_table(:rivers)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

Comment: So it hasn't successfully completed.  Try running it again with `rake db:migrate --trace` and it should give you a proper error stack trace which will help diagnose the problem.

Comment: result of that: Jennys-MacBook-Pro:dashboard jennymandl$ rake db:migrate --trace
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
== 20140609150804 CreateRivers: migrating =====================================
-- create_table(:rivers)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:
undefined method `write' for :display:Symbol/Users/jennymandl/Desktop/dashboard/db/migrate/20140609150804_create_rivers.rb:5:in `display'

Comment: Please can you edit your question and add the entire stack trace for the error?  I don't understand that specific error listed there and i'm hoping that the lower lines in the stack might shed some light.

Comment: Also, try deleting your database, creating it again and then running the migrations from scratch.

Comment: it's too long for a comment so I will edit the question and add it

Comment: Yep, that's what i asked you to do :)

Comment: any chance we could skype?

Comment: Did you try deleting the database, creating it again and then doing `rake db:migrate`

Comment: Do `rake db:create`. Can't skype, sorry.